# Agregar Spinner a mi boton

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy trabajando con un `spinner` en un botón. No logro agregar mi `spinner` de manera correcta, éste es una imagen `.gif` que al cargar la página aparece el spinner en toda la ventana y debería aparecer al momento de dar click en el evento onclick del botón.

Éste es mi código:

```js
function executeAjaxRequest() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
  });
}
```

```css
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('../gif/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249, 249, 249);
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
  <button type="button" id="navegar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="executeAjaxRequest();">Navegar</button>
  <div class="loading"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices **no logro agregar mi spinner de manera correcta**? [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/134074/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo detalles

Comment: Mas bien si muestra mi spinner solo que no lo hace en la funciona al dar click en el botón lo que pasa es que el spinner aparece cuando cargo la pagina y lo que necesito es que sea al entrar en el evento onclick del boton

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/134074/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Hey te puedes basar un spinner sencillo con fa fa awesome https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210417/font-awesome-animated-spinner-through-background

Comment: @DudaLoca Aquí te dejo un link que puede servirte de acuerdo a lo que preguntas: [Cargar Animación Spinner](https://stephanwagner.me/loading-spinner-with-animation) . Esta en ingles. Si puedes entenderlo, mejor, sino prueba usando los códigos que brindan. (en la demo utiliza ajaxrequest)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function executeAjaxRequest() {
  $("#boxLoading").addClass("loading")
  setTimeout(() => $("#boxLoading").removeClass("loading"), 3000);
}
```

```css
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('https://www.tmogroup.asia/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/001gif.gif?x96783') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249, 249, 249);
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
  <button type="button" id="navegar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="executeAjaxRequest();">Navegar</button>
  <div id="boxLoading"></div>
</div>
```

Agrega la clase del spinner cuando se ejecute el evento executeAjaxRequest, no antes. Además cuando termines de realizar tus acciones no olvides de remover dicha clase.